# Stupid Question on Trajectory

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the dynamical system in $\mathbb R^n$ where $x_{k+1}=I_nx_k$.

Is the origin a saddle point, a repeller, or an attractor?

All eigenvalues are $1$.

I understand what's going on, the trajectory is a single point, which is the initial vector $x_0$.

But it's not being repelled, attracted, or "saddled."

Would it be *none*, then?

Comment: There are no stupid questions - only stupid answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed "none of the above".